# Post processing json in Apache cxf

Tags: java, json, spring, apache, cxf

I am using Apache cxf to make a rest call. The response is as follows:

```
{
    "student_id"  : [1, 2, 3],
    "student_name": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

How can I map this json to the DTO which is as follows?

```
public class StudentDTO {
    Integer id;
    String name;
}
```

The end result needs to give me a List of StudentDTO 
1. Does jackson have some kind of a mapper that can process the above json? 
2. Is there some kind of postprocessor in apache cxf which would let me manipulate the json so that I can convert the resultant json as follows:

```
[
    {
        "student_id": 1,
        "student_name": "a"
    },
    {
        "student_id": 2,
        "student_name": "b"
    },
    {
        "student_id": 3,
        "student_name": "c"
    }
]

List<StudentDTO> students = WebClientFactory.createFrom(dummyClient, "dummyClient").path("students")
                           .getCollection(StudentDTO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom messagebodywriter, though its tedious task. I believe its better to change server side implementation if allowed, as the design looks flawed, else you can implement a adapter/bridge design pattern, implement a intermediate class.

```
public class StudentDTOIn {
    Integer[] student_id;
    String[] student_name;
}
```